# Sending values of several checkboxes with same ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

I have a table inside a form. It has two columns, the first one is a checkbox and the second is an input.

Here its structure:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="choose" id="choose" class="choose">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" class="item" >
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It is filled with info from my database so it may have several rows.

The form is submitted via a javascript function to a js file and then, thanks to jQuery’s ajax, all the parameters go to my controller php file.

As I want to send to my php all the values form the text input, in my js file I do:

```
       var arrayItem= [];
        $(".item").each(function(){
            arrayItem.push($(this).val());
        })
    params += '&items='+ arrayItem;
.
.
    //So I can do: 
        $.ajax ({
            url: myPHPUrl,
            data: params,
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            success: function (data, textStatus)
            {   
            }
        });
```

Now I need to do the same with the checkboxes but I don’t know how to proceed.

Can anyone please help me with it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The same code should work with checkboxes. You only need to keep in mind that send only checked items. i.e. `$(".choose:checked")`

Comment: I agree with @Imdad, moreover do not forget to do not put multiple controls with the same ID inside the page (it's an error). Side question: why do you '&items=' for your data? A POST request does not need to be encoded like an URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   var arrayItem= [];
    $(".choose:checked").each(function(index, elem){
        //you could store them like a key-valuepair so you no where the value belongs to.
        //you can take the ID of the elem parm inside the for each and store it with the control id.
        arrayItem.push(elem.val());
    })
params += '&items='+ arrayItem;
```